# SQL query from dplyr shows NULL

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dplyr

I have a `dplyr` object `c1` created using the following codes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my.sqlite3", create = T)
women_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, women, temporary = TRUE)
c1 <- filter(women_sqlite, height == 62)
```

Now, I want to view the SQL query generated by dplyr. As suggested in dplyr [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) the command should be `c1$query`. However, this does not show the SQL query anymore, instead shows null as below

```
>c1$query
NULL
```

I am expecting an output similar to the query below

```
SELECT *
FROM `women`
WHERE (`height` = 62.0)
```

I will appreciate if anyone can give me some hints on what is going on. Is it possible to retrieve the desired query anymore?

My R session information is as follows

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_1.0.0 DBI_0.5-1     dplyr_0.5.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 tools_3.3.2    tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.8
```

Comment: Your use of `copy_to` looks suspicious to me.  This function should take two data frames as input, not a `tbl_sql` object, which is what `src_sqlite` returns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please refer to dplyr [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html). The example given there also shows `NULL` for `c1$query`

Comment: Have you tried `show_query` ?

Comment: I just used `show_query(c1)` and it gave the desired output. Why will not `c1$query` work? It worked for previous versions.

Comment: Not sure, I am not too familiar with this package.  Maybe the versions have changed.  Anyway, glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the implementation of SQL data sources changed from dplyr 0.4.3 to 0.5. To get the query (and execution plan), use `explain`:

```
> explain(c1)
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `women`
WHERE (`height` = 62.0)


<PLAN>
   addr       opcode p1 p2 p3       p4 p5 comment
1     0         Init  0 13  0          00    <NA>
2     1     OpenRead  0  2  1        2 00    <NA>
3     2       Rewind  0 11  0          00    <NA>
4     3       Column  0  0  1          00    <NA>
5     4 RealAffinity  1  0  0          00    <NA>
6     5           Ne  2 10  1 (BINARY) 6d    <NA>
7     6         Copy  1  3  0          00    <NA>
8     7       Column  0  1  4          00    <NA>
9     8 RealAffinity  4  0  0          00    <NA>
10    9    ResultRow  3  2  0          00    <NA>
11   10         Next  0  3  0          01    <NA>
12   11        Close  0  0  0          00    <NA>
13   12         Halt  0  0  0          00    <NA>
14   13  Transaction  1  0  2        0 01    <NA>
15   14    TableLock  1  2  0    women 00    <NA>
16   15         Real  0  2  0       62 00    <NA>
17   16         Goto  0  1  0          00    <NA>
```

The `explain` function works in both dplyr 0.4.3 and 0.5; you shouldn't rely on hidden implementation details like extracting the `query` component.